# How dangerous is TransportCredentialOnly when combined with CredentialType="Windows"?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I'm configuring a WCF service for use on an internal network (Active Directory domain) and don't much care about whether eavesdroppers can read the contents of web service requests and responses. However, I *do* care about bad guys being able to steal credentials and impersonate other users.

I know that if I create a WCF web service endpoint with BasicHttpBinding and set its security mode to "TransportCredentialOnly", then the SOAP requests and responses are *not* encrypted.

From the [Microsoft Patterns and Practices book](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650862.aspx):

> **TransportCredentialOnly** Mutual authentication is provided at the
>   transport level; no message protection is provided. This option is
>   available only on basicHttpBinding.

If I configure the binding as follows:

```
  <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
  </security>
```

The mutual authentication described in my quote above should be conducted using Kerberos. That means I don't need to include any credentials in the SOAP request text, since the server has already identified the client's Windows identity. Unless I'm greatly mistaken, the actual Kerberos authentication exchange should be inherently encrypted and secured, correct?

So what I want to know is, if I configure the service with TransportCredentialOnly and clientCredentialType="Windows", will I be exposing anything in clear text which could then be used to impersonate a web service client (replay attacks etc)? Can I get away without setting up SSL, deploying certificates and so on? Is mutual Kerberos authentication sufficient in this case?

[This CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36289/8-steps-to-enable-windows-authentication-on-WCF-Ba) instructs people to use this approach to enable Windows Authentication over the BasicHttpBinding, but does not comment on how safe this would be.